# How to increase Salesforce file download speed for users in China

Tags: attachment, files, emailfileattachment, content-delivery

We are using Email to Case and have a lot of emails with attachments captured in the system. Customers use email from Salesforce with Attachments/Files to negotiate contracts and exchange invoice / purchase order documents with their customers. When the users from China send these out to customers and try and access / download the files from Salesforce files, they are seeing huge delay in preview / download times. Users outside the region have no issues viewing / downloading the files. The users now take about 10 - 15 minutes to download / view a 8 MB file that takes 2 seconds or less outside of China.

Please share any native or CDN / alternate solutions that might solve this problem.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318729&type=1&mode=1 Even the article didn't help. Raise a case with Salesforce support so that they can check the network logs and provide you a valid solution.

Comment: We did and got the same article along with a recommendation of http://en.chinacache.com/  . Wondering if anybody has implemented it and can share their experience.